# Using SUM in a query to retrieve non negative values

Tags: mysql, yii

I am trying to use the Yii framework to perform a SUM() in a query and return the data in the 'Yii' way.

I have a table called 'codes' that has the following structure (i've omitted all the non relevant columns for clarity)

```
+--------+----------+-------------+
| user_id | points  | classroom_id|
+---------+---------+-------------+
|    2    |   10    |     219     |
|    2    |   30    |     219     |
|    2    |  -20    |     219     |
|    2    |  100    |     219     |
|    2    |  -50    |     219     |
+--------+---------+--------------+
```

My query is currently as follows:

```
SELECT user_id, points, SUM(points) AS current_points
FROM `codes`
WHERE classroom_id = 219
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I basically need to modify this query to return 'total_points' (these are all the points without subtracting the negative points)

So I would expect:
current_points - 70
total_points - 140

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering negative values using the sign function:

```
  SELECT user_id, points, SUM(GREATEST(SIGN(points),0) * points) AS current_points
    FROM `codes`
   WHERE classroom_id = 219
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Alternative:

```
SUM ( CASE WHEN points > 0 THEN points ELSE 0 END )
```

Comment: Damn that was fast! Thanks mate, will accept in 9mins